# C# From an Array/List of Tasks how to assign them to specific data

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a .csv file that contains data that require some heavy computations..
The tricky thing is that on each line there are specific group of data that are characterized as  "a","b","c"....

For example : a,1,2,3,4-b,1,3,4,5-c,2,3,4,6....

I want each of this group to get processes separately...so 1 thread for "a",1 thread for "b" and so on...
Any idea on how to pick out of the Array or List the Task[1] --> a,Task[2] -->b (the match should be based on the fact that the line actually has the values a,b,c...as described above)
One last thing each row can have a varied number of data groups e.g

```
1st line --> {a},{b},{c}
2nd line --> {b},{d},{e}
10th line --> {a},{c},{e}
```

So the assignment  should be dynamic
Thanks for help

Comment: Its not the best choise to process one file with multiple threads. You should read it to some string buffer first.

Comment: Lets say that this is not the issue...but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Then just find the positions of all letters from 'a' to 'z' and slice the string.

Comment: [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) can help.

Comment: The problem is not Splitting the String...i have done it...the problem is that i want to process each occurrence of each data group in a separate Task...

Comment: You probably want to use `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: Do you have an example for `Parallel.ForEach` suitable for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to process your files.

```
    Dictionary<string, Task> tasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
    Dictionary<string, Queue<IEnumerable<string>>> queues = new Dictionary<string, Queue<IEnumerable<string>>>();

    foreach( var line in File.ReadAllLines("file.txt"))
    {
         var parts = line.Split('-');
         foreach( var part in parts )
         {
              var keyValues = part.Split(',');
              if( !tasks.ContainsKey( keyValues[0] ) )
              {
                  var queue = new Queue<IEnumerable<string>>();
                  queues[keyValues[0]] = queue;
                  queue.Enqueue(keyValues.Skip(1));
                  var task = Task.Run(() => Process(queue));
                  tasks[keyValues[0]] = task;
              }
              else
              {
                  queues[keyValues[0]].Enqueue(keyValues.Skip(1));
              }
         }
    }
```